# Need to add HTML characters to Select list

Tags: forms, theming

I have a form using the FAPI that has a select list of currency values as one of its inputs. 
I need to be able to add HTML characters such as `&euro; $pound; &yen;`

The problem is that Drupal is filtering the input and not displaying the desired symbols, but displaying the actual html codes as displayed above.

Is there any way of having Drupal not filter my list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can and should put the UTF-8 characters for the symbols in your list. HTML entities are a relic from the past when it was possible that some symbols did not have a representation in the active code page. Thus simply use €, £, and ¥ in your lists.

Drupal is UTF-8 from back to front: use it.

Comment: thanks for your simple reply, unfortunately it was not quite as simple as that to do. inserting UTF-8 characters alone might not work. I had to: check php.ini to ensure my default charset was ut8-f, make sure my headers had <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in them AND MOST IMPORTANTLY.. make sure your pages are saved as utf-8. in my case I had to right click on my page in eclipse to bring up the properties dialog. From here I had to ensure that he text-file encoding attribute was set to UTF-8. I had to do this for every page , eg. page.tpl and any includes

Comment: This should all be standard when developing in Drupal. The content-type meta tag is added by Drupal (at least in D6, perhaps that in D7 it is left up to the theme, but even then each and every theme outputs utf-8 as charset). And Eclipse, well yeah, it is a shame that Eclipse ships with something else than utf-8 as default. Don't forget to set your workspace standard to utf-8 to prevent the same problem with future projects.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution you may use #after_build property for your form element.

lets say you have $options variable with options for select

```
$form['myselect']['options'] = $options;
$form['myselect']['#after_build'][] = 'custom_select_formatter';
```

then you have to define your formatter function like

```
function  custom_select_formatter($form_element, $form_state){

$options = $form_element['#options'] //you can use your option values
}
```

here you may redefine your select element even you may #theme add #prefix #suffix

another probably solution is maybe that l() function [in this example](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7#comment-13919) uses html option when creating links with images maybe select element also uses it